# jquery wait for php update to finish

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

rapportupdate.php contains a php update script which works fine.
After this update has finished I want Beheer.click() to execute, so i can show the updated table. How do I get Beheer.click() to wait until the php update has finished.

```
$.ajax(
{
  type:"get",
  url: "rapportupdate.php",
  data: {variable1 : idnr ,
  variable2 : rapportnaam
},
success: function(data)
{
  $('#div1').html(data, function() 
  $("#Beheer").click();
}
```

Comment: It should be already the case so what is your issue? BTW, this isn't valid: `$('#div1').html(data, function()`

Comment: yes, it was syntax error. just didnt see it.
works now, tx

Comment: Well, next time open your console instead of asking useless question... I don't want to be rude but sometimes it's needed

Comment: well its not needed now. I just started out with jquery like 2 weeks a go, give me some time to learn.

Comment: That's ok, like i said, i din't really want to be rude here, my bad and GL. Anyway, you have at least learnt that you should always open your console for debugging purpose, not so bad after all ;)

Comment: thats right, and i also just learned how to pass variables with console.log, so the day is not completely lost

Answer (score 0):

$("#Beheer").trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

You can set async to false `async (default: true)`.
Then the Script is waiting for the request of the ajax.

```
$.ajax(
{
  type:"get",
  url: "rapportupdate.php",
  data: {variable1 : idnr ,
  variable2 : rapportnaam
  async: false,
},
success: function(data)
{
  $('#div1').html(data, function() 
  $("#Beheer").click();
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Please don't and anyway, OP is triggering click event in success callback so it is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax's success callback as:

```
$.ajax({
type:"get",
  url: "rapportupdate.php",
  data: {variable1 : idnr ,
  variable2 : rapportnaam,
success: function(e){                   
  $('#div1').html(data, function() 
  $("#Beheer").click(); // this will trigger only after result came in success
    },  
});
```

Comment: html jquery method is synchronous, it doesn't accept any callback, why it should?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're almost there:

```
$.ajax(
 {
    type:"get",
    url: "rapportupdate.php",
    data: {variable1 : idnr ,
    variable2 : rapportnaam
 },
 success: function(data)
 {
   //$('#div1').html(data, function()  This line will throw error..
   $("#Beheer").trigger('click');
 }, error: function() {} 
});
```